# Want to make image in Div tag to fill the brower screen bigger or smaller

Tags: css, html

Want to make image in Div tag to fill the browser screen bigger or smaller, so image is perfect size for any screen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body style="margin:0; height:100vh;">
    <div align="center" style="vertical-align:top; border-top: 0px">
        <img src="images/Main.jpg" border="0">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this? background? banner?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Qieyna/2LEHd/1/).You can use width:100% and height:100% to the image in div tag since you want the image fill up the browser when resizing it (browser).

```
<img src="http://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/ice-cream-cone-29168018.jpg" border="0" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
```

Comment: This will distort the image.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="images/Main.jpg" border="0" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;">
```